# How to include the "wait" command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the script (command) in powershell mode. I have created the following command and I wanted to include "wait".

As this file GUI_Test.tcfl has some steps (4) which will requires to wait for some time to execute other step (Lets say, step1 will execute and then it needs to wait for 30 sec and then needs to execute step2 , similarly rest continues)

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\GUITESTER_\Editor\GUITester.exe`" C:\GUITESTER\Scripts\GUI_Test.tcfl"
```

I recreated it by including "wait" and then killing the exe.

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\GUITESTER_\Editor\GUITester.exe`" C:\GUITESTER\Scripts\GUI_Test.tcfl" -Wait; taskkill /IM GUITester.exe /F
```

I received the following error as:

```
Invoke-Expression : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Wait'.
At line:1 char:134
+ ... tor.exe`" C:\GUITESTER_\Scripts\GUI_Test.tcfl" -Wait
+                                                                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Comment: `invoke-expression` does not have a `-wait` parameter. You need to add `sleep-start -seconds X` after you start the command before you run the next command giving ample time. Or the executable should give proper exit code, etc. to have something to indicate it is fully running before the `wait/timeout/sleep` for whatever condition needs to occur before you run the next process in your logic as a whole. This is all trivial but `iex` does not have a `-wait` parameter like `start-process`

Comment: Are your two questions one question? One version has `Start-Process` the other has `Invoke-Expression.` I think you need to edit and combine into one and kill the other...

Comment: Yes, first will start the exe and then it will run the script. I have used Invoke-Expression to combine both and not able to kill the exe

Comment: `Start-Sleep -Seconds 30`